# Не пишет переменную в cmd :(

Tags: cmd, bat

В названии все написано

````
:p1
cls
set t1 = 1
echo t1%
set t1 = t1 + 1
echo 2
echo 2
echo 2
echo 2
echo 2
echo 2
echo 2
@timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK
goto p1```
````

Comment: а разве вывод переменной не так нужно делать `echo %t1%`

Comment: кроме этого для вычисления выражений используется параметр /a. Например, **set /a t1=t1+1**

Comment: насчет t1% обычная опечатка, но спасибо